# Anki does not run on Ubuntu Budgie 18.10

Tags: qt, anki

When I start Anki on Ubuntu Budgie 18.10 I get the following two messages:

> 1. Qt version issue  You are using Qt version 5.11.1.  Anki has only been tested upstream with version Qt 5.9.x.  Upstream suggests only
>      using version Qt 5.9.x, and a standalone version containing the
>      required libraries can be downloaded from the Anki website. 
>      Continuing with this Debian version could potentially lead to loss of
>      data (though this is unlikely).  Are you sure you want to continue?

and

> 2. Fehler beim Start: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                 File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/main.py", line 50, in **init**
>      self.setupUI()   File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/main.py", line 75, in setupUI
>      self.setupMainWindow()   File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/main.py", line 585, in setupMainWindow
>      tweb = self.toolbarWeb = aqt.webview.AnkiWebView()   File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/webview.py", line 114, in **init**
>      self.focusProxy().installEventFilter(self) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'installEventFilter'

I installed Anki via the terminal with

> sudo apt-get install anki

and apt-cache policy anki returns

> anki:
>     Installiert:           2.1.0+dfsg-1
>     Installationskandidat: 2.1.0+dfsg-1
>     Versionstabelle:
>    *** 2.1.0+dfsg-1 500
>           500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
>           500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe i386 Packages
>           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: How did you installed Anki? Please add output of `apt-cache policy anki` to the question.

Comment: What is Bungie 18.10?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Meant to write Ubuntu Budgie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on Ubuntu MATE 18.10.

So the problem really exists. I reported it to launchpad as [bug 1819063](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/anki/+bug/1819063).

We can fix it with installation patched version of Anki from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~torkvemada/+archive/ubuntu/torkvemada?field.series_filter=cosmic):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:torkvemada/torkvemada
sudo apt-get install anki
```

Afterwards it will launch normally.