# Anki doesn't start in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, anki

I've installed Anki from "Ubuntu software" and as an addition installed this: `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils` (because of known issue) and it still doesn't work. Could someone please explain to me what should I do to fix the problem?

**Upd1:**
After launching from terminal (as @Emmet asked) the output is here:

```
su@uranus:~$ anki
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/anki", line 6, in <module>
    import aqt
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import aqt.forms
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/forms/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from . import about
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/forms/about.py", line 42, in <module>
    from aqt.webview import AnkiWebView
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/webview.py", line 90, in <module>
    class AnkiWebView(QWebEngineView):
NameError: name 'QWebEngineView' is not defined
```

Comment: Launch it from terminal, paste the output here.

Comment: @Emmet added an output to the body

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1123878/66509 for links. You can request package build for Disco or grab package from cosmic manually [from link](https://launchpad.net/~torkvemada/+archive/ubuntu/torkvemada/+files/anki_2.1.7+dfsg-1cosmic1_all.deb).

Comment: This is a bug and should be reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

The only problem here is a forgotten import in the Python script mentioned at the bottom of the traceback :

```
    File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/webview.py", line 90, in <module>
      class AnkiWebView(QWebEngineView):
NameError: name 'QWebEngineView' is not defined
```

Just open webview.py and add the import needed:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
```

(There are a bunch of other imports missing from QtWebEngineWidgets aside from QWebEngineView, so it's easier to just import them all)

Comment: This is already in the works for being fixed - see my answer and the attached bug.  A fix was already released in Eoan (devel release), its pending SRU team intervention to release in disco-updates

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem today :D 
this the steps  how i fixed it

First remove anki:

```
sudo apt-get remove anki
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

Second install anki from this steps https://apps.ankiweb.net/

1) Downloads Anki from website

https://apps.ankiweb.net/downloads/current/anki-2.1.11-linux-amd64.tar.bz2

2) Installation

```
tar xjf anki-2.1.11-amd64.tar.bz2
cd anki-2.1.11-linux-amd64
sudo make install
```

3) to run anki

use this `/usr/local/share/anki/bin/anki` write it on terminal

Or

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/anki
```

and write in /usr/bin/anki file this code

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
/usr/local/share/anki/bin/anki
```

save file
and write on terminal

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/bin/anki
```

now you can run anki just when you write `anki` on terminal

congratulation :D

Answer (score 1):

You're not importing QWebPage.

Try adding this import to the top of your script:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754786/nameerror-name-qwebpage-is-not-defined

Comment: There is no user script involved, only a package installed with apt from the Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 0):

This is a KNOWN BUG and is already in the process of being fixed.

I have already uploaded a fix to the repos for this.  It awaits SRU team release into the `disco-updates` pocket of the repositories.

More details at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/anki/+bug/1825722

Answer (score 0):

FYI, a [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/anki/+bug/1825722) was released as of 19.04. So the workaround shouldn't be necessary from now on. Still, the upstream Debian package seems to be barely maintained and affected by the same bug.